# Flutter CLI - Omit the spinner

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I have an automated build server that logs the output of programs that are run during the build.

When I use the Flutter CLI during the build, the CLI prints a loading spinner animation that fills the log with gibberish (`ΓòÉΓòÉΓòÉΓòÉΓòÉΓòÉΓòÉΓòÉΓòÉΓòÉ...`):

[image]

Is there any way to omit the spinner? I have already tried `--no-color` and `--quiet`, to no avail.

Comment: Might be able to pipe it through `cat`.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveNewton, that worked. If you would like to submit an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad it worked—you did all the work so the answer is yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

As @Dave Newton suggested, piping the command through `cat` suppressed the animation and kept the log clean.

I am actually using PowerShell, so you can use `cat`, `echo` or `Write-Host` (they're all the same command):

```
flutter pub get | echo
```